# SVG align rect to bottom-right of parent element

Tags: html, svg, alignment, rect

i'm trying to draw a rect in SVG (300x300 px) and align 4 smaller rects in each corner of the parent Rect (10x10 px), but every small child rect has the full size of the parent rect.

```
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <svg height="10" width="10" />
    <svg height="10" width="10" />
    <svg height="10" width="10" />
    <svg height="10" width="10" />
</svg>
```

You can view my results here: http://jsfiddle.net/8tY3b/

If I set the width or height of the inner SVG Elements to 10px it works with every edge except the bottom right one.

Is there a way to align a child element to the bottom right of his parent element?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to embed svg elements or draw rectangles? In case you're satisfied with the latter, here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495978/svg-circled-text-on-textpath-center-align  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   width="15cm" height="15cm"
   viewBox="0 0 300 300"
   preserveAspectRatio="none"
   style="background-color:white; border: solid 1px black;"
>
    <rect fill="green" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" height="10" width="10" x="0" y="0"/>
    <rect fill="green" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" height="10" width="10" x="290" y="0"/>
    <rect fill="green" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" height="10" width="10" x="0" y="290"/>
    <rect fill="green" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" height="10" width="10" x="290" y="290"/>
</svg>
```

The value `none` for the attribute `preserveAspectRatio` allows for arbitrary scaling.

Comment: Thanks, i want to draw rects, but I forgot to mention, that i need to freely scale the outer element. It should not be fixed at a specific size. I thought there must be a way to only change the size of the outer element an the inner rects preserve their position in the corners without scripting.

Comment: you can scale the svg container to whatever suits your needs by modifying its `width` and `height`attributes. the content will follow accordingly. in a similar vein you may define groups of elements (eg. 1 big rect with 4 small rects, one in each corner) in their individual coordinate system and position/scale it using the appropriate transformation (`treansform`attribute; not part of the sample code).

Comment: I will try this. Does this way preserve the size of the inner rects? They need to stay at the size of 10px.